# How to pass a date function in a dynamic sql query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT @sql='

select 
    *
from (
    select ''Ongoing'' AS Ongoing,
    Coalesce(COUNT(project),0) AS project, Coalesce(COUNT(year(u.PlannedStartDate)),0) as [y]
    from Projects u  WHERE 
    u.actualstartdate IS  NULL 
    AND u.Startdate < ''+GETDATE()+''
    AND ID ='''+@ID+'''  

  ) Data
PIVOT (
  COUNT(project)
  FOR [y]
  IN (
    ' + @Years + '
  )
) PivotTable
'
```

Here I want to pass the cur date but it's not working..
this is because the value of GETDATE() is not coming in the string

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting GETDATE() to a varchar like this:  CAST(GETDATE() AS varchar)

Answer (score 2):

change `AND u.Startdate < ''+GETDATE()+''` to AND `u.Startdate < GETDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes around it I would think

```
SELECT @sql='

select * from ( select ''Ongoing'' AS Ongoing, Coalesce(COUNT(project),0) AS project,
Coalesce(COUNT(year(u.PlannedStartDate)),0) as [y] from Projects u 
WHERE u.actualstartdate IS   NULL AND u.Startdate < GETDATE() AND ID ='''+@ID+'''

) Data PIVOT ( COUNT(project) FOR [y] IN ( ' + @Years + ' ) ) PivotTable '
```

Comment: This will not work in a string function. It takes as GETDATE() only not the date value.